# Update a key value inside an array in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, fetch

I'm having problems trying to update from mongoDB the "name" key inside gardens.

```
{
    name: "Adky",
    email: "dry@fsdf.co.uk",
    lastConected: "",
    gardens: [{
      name: '',
      location_id: "43567",
      plants: []
    }, {
      name: '',
      location_id: "234092",
      plants: []
    }, {
      name:'',
      location_id: "22355",
      plants: []
    }]
  }
```

I tried

```
collection
      .findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: ObjectId(id)
      },{
        "gardens.location_id": req.params.location_id
      }, {
        $set: {
          "gardens.$.name": updatedData.name
        }
      }, {
        returnOriginal: false
      }
```

But This error comes up

```
{
  "status": 500,
  "error": {
    "driver": true,
    "name": "MongoError"
  }
}
```

Don't really know what to do here..
I was thinking that the problem should be in the way I'm accessing into gardens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FindOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) takes 3 parameters

```
   db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   <filter>,
   <update document or aggregation pipeline>, // Changed in MongoDB 4.2
   {
     projection: <document>,
     sort: <document>,
     maxTimeMS: <number>,
     upsert: <boolean>,
     returnNewDocument: <boolean>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
   }
)
```

but you are passing `4 parameters`, you can update your code

```
collection
    .findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: ObjectId(id), "gardens.location_id": req.params.location_id
    }, {
        $set: {
            "gardens.$.name": updatedData.name
        }
    }, {
        returnOriginal: false
    })
```

You can find your document using both `_id` and `location_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use that code

```
  db.testers.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: ObjectId("5dee7d425a13b401c7722c28")
  ,
    "gardens.location_id": "234092"
  }, {
    $set: {
      "gardens.$.name": 'tst34'
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').update_one(
{"gardens.name": '' },
{$set: {"gardens.name" : "New_Name"}})
```